# how to run the same code for multiple groups within a data frame in R?

Tags: r, loops

I've never used loops or apply functions in R and I realized that my code looks messy because I keep repeating the same lines of code over and over.

I have a data set named "behavior" with different replicate groups of my study group("EC1:EC8; N1:N12), and I want to run the exact same set of functions to each of these groups separately.

What I'm doing is simply copying the whole code below, but swapping every EC6 for let's say EC7. In the end I get 20 repetitions of the same thing which is pretty time consuming, inefficient and amateur. I just wanted to know how to automatize the whole thing while matching the file names to the group name. Thank you so much (code below).

```
    EC6 <- filter(behavior, groupID == "EC6")
EC6_scores <-elo.seq(winner= EC6$MaleID, loser= EC6$FemaleID, Date= EC6$NewDate)
EC6_result <- EC6_scores[["mat"]]
EC6_result<- melt(EC6_result,
                  na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "ELO_SCORE",
                  factorsAsStrings = TRUE)
EC6_result <- EC6_result %>%
  rename(Male=Var2, Day = Var1)
ggplot(EC6_result, aes(x = Day, y = ELO_SCORE, group = Male, colour=Male)) +
  geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=EC6_result$Day,labels = EC6_result$Day) +
  labs(title = "EC6") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: In general, if you want to do some calculations by group you would use `df %>% group_by(group_column) %>% some calculation`

Comment: Yeah, you should look into `group_by` and `summarise` from the `dplyr` package. Here it is hard to understand what will work, because I am not familiar with whatever packages contain `elo.seq` and `melt`. As some guidance, to try and place this chunk of code into a for loop, you could make a character vector of your group names - `groups <- c("EC1", "EC2")` - and use `for (group in groups) {your code}`. The main problem is that you seem to want to save an object (`EC6_result`). I suggest you try to instead sequentially add these objects to a list or data.frame.

Comment: thanks Calum. Yeah, intuitively I thought a loop would be the correct solution but the problem is that for every command line I need it to be updated with the new group name, since I want results for every single group. Hence my just using ctrl f on 20 copies of the code and swapping the group names. it is straight forward but it seems very idiotic to me, because im sure there is a faster and more compact way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to develop the code completely since the original dataset is not available but, if using  a loop I would do something like this.

```
for (group in 1:length(unique(df$groupColumn))){

  currentGroup = unique(df$groupColumn)[group]

  groupFilter <- filter(behavior, groupID == currentGroup)

  group_result <- groupFilter[["mat"]]
  ...
  ggplot(...)
}
```

`wheredf$groupColumn` is the column of the original dataframe that contains all the different groups.

But, to what other useres posted in the comments it is more efficient to use a `dplyr` solution.

Comment: You probably want `1:length()` or seq_along()` in your for loop definition. And it would be better to do `unique(df$groupColumn)` once before the loop, rather than every iteration.